# Get XMMS2 to call outside script on automatic playlist advance?

Tags: linux, mp3, script, media-player

Is there a way to get XMMS2 to call an outside script when it advances in a playlist - either automatically or via manual intervention (e.g. xmms2 next)?

The goal is to have balloons pop up on my desktop to tell me what new song has started playing, and I really, really don't want to write a background daemon that polls 'xmms2 info' or 'xmms2 current' if there's a way to get it to issue the callback.

Answer (score 0):

XMMS2 only calls scripts or programs on startup and shutdown. There is no function built in that calls programs when it advances in the playlist.

But you could write a small client program in python, perl or ruby that connects to XMMS2 and uses broadcast_current_id to get notified when the current song changes.

For displaying that information you can then use libnotify, like someone already told in an answer to another question.

Or you can use an existing notification client, like http://code.google.com/p/xmms2-notify/ (Either directly or as reference)

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click -> Popup menu -> Preferences -> General plugins -> Song change plugin

enable this and configure the command to be launched when a new song starts.

Comment: That answer might work for XMMS, but the question was about XMMS2

Answer (score 0):

esperanza, a xmms2 client has the notification feature you want.

Answer (score 0):

Both `xmms2tray` and `esperanza` provide popup notifications, although each requires running a client program.  There is currently no plugin providing `libnotify` integration for xmms2, which would be one of the better ways to get such notifications.